# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when trying to access the website on mobile data

Tags: ssl, iis, networking

Scenario: A Windows IIS server is installed on an IP, my subdomain points to that IP. The website works fine when I access it from on WiFi but as soon as I switch to the mobile data I get the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

I've added a binding, where I can access the website on PORT 400. I've checked the SSL as well on SSL Checker and everything is fine on that part.

I want the website to be accessible to the default https port. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Try to clear your browser's cache and try again. if you wan to accessible to the website default https port, you can set it in the Site Bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Since the exact domain is not known I can only speculate about the cause of the problem.

But a common problem is that the site is configured for IPv4 but not properly configured for IPv6, even though it resolves to an IPv6 address. Mobile networks often use IPv6 while internet access using WiFi often uses only IPv4, which can explain the difference you encounter.

[SSL checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) only does rudimentary checks and checks only IPv4. Use [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) instead which checks both IPv4 and IPv6 setups and also checks all visible IP addresses for the domain instead only a single one.

Comment: I've checked the domain(portal.padmeshdigital.in) on SSLLabs, the assessment failed for the IPv6 address. Looks like I have to configure the server for IPv6 address. But what I cannot understand is that the domain was working absolutely fine few weeks back but now it is not. Will try configuring the server and keep you updated!
Thanks!

Comment: @PoweredByCaffein:  Hard to tell what made the difference between your tests a few weeks ago and now. It might be a change in the server configuration or it might  be that you've accessed the site with IPv4 only in the past and never with IPv6. Trying to access by IPv6 requires several things: the internet provider (which means the mobile provider when accessing by mobile data) must provide a IPv6 address, the OS and browser must actually prefer IPv6 instead of IPv4 and there must be also a IPv6 DNS record for the domain.